# Using DataGridView to add, remove and update records in PostgreSQL

Tags: c#, postgresql, datagridview

I use a DataGridView to display rows from PostgreSQL, which works fine. Now whnt I want to implement is an editor that can add, edit and remove rows from that `DataGridView`. To do so, I have created event handlers to handle these events. In the handlers, I will insert, update or delete the row in my PostgreSQL database.

```
dgOrderLines.RowsAdded += 
   new DataGridViewRowsAddedEventHandler(dgOrderLines_RowsAdded);
dgOrderLines.RowsRemoved += 
   new DataGridViewRowsRemovedEventHandler(dgOrderLines_RowsRemoved);
dgOrderLines.CellEndEdit += 
   new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dgOrderLines_CellEndEdit);
```

However, if I run this code, I see events being fired when I first populate the `DataGridView` like this:

```
dgOrderLines.DataSource = Program.DB.GetView("someview");
```

(`Program.DB.GetView` returns a `DataTable`.)

Now, if I would be to implement the event handlers, I will be adding and removing records in my database, every time I load my `DatagridView`. Is there a way to prevent that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it.

When setting the `DataSource` before setting the event handlers, they do not get called.